# Problem while playing video in jsp - How to redirect to another page after playing the video?

Tags: java, html, jsp

I am playing a mpeg video file in jsp. After the video is played, i want to redirect the user to another page. But, am getting redirected to the other page before the video is completed.

```
<embed src="http://localhost:1000/myapp/media/DELTA.MPG" />

<script type="text/javascript">
window.location = "http://www.yahoo.com";
</script>
```

Is it possible to specify any attribute in the 'embed' tag to tell the browser that the user should be redirected ONLY after the play is over?

Comment: I think it is not possible, but if you can try HTML5 video tag it has events to handle such tings try w3school to learn how.

Comment: Thanks, but html5 video tag is not supported in most browsers.

Comment: yes, in old ones, you can also try to write a flash player, or can find free plash player on the net, that might help you.

Comment: Why do we need to write a flash player for just triggering an action when the media play is ended? Is it so complex?

Comment: Because html, **again** in my opinion can't do this, so if you need this functionality please try some other options. Free flash video player can be an option.

Comment: Okay, is it possible to play mpeg, avi files also using flash player? or will it play only flash files?

Comment: I mean, do i need to convert the file to .flv format before playing them?

Comment: this is an issue, but for this you can covert movies in flv using FFMPEG.

Comment: **I mean, do i need to convert the file to .flv format before playing them?**, Yes you have to.

Comment: Thanks Asad. Will take this approach.

Comment: you are welcome but close this question and marked solved.

Comment: Okay, but i dont know how to close a question in stackoverflow

Comment: me too, I didn't asked any question so I don't know. Ok any how good luck to what you are developing.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the video is played without any pauses or delays, you can write a javascript function which would start a timer to redirect the user to a new page.

The duration of the video should be passed to that function when the page is loaded.